# Modifying spacing inside align

Tags: align

I am trying to type this into LaTeX, but I have difficulties with the spacing between the equalities.
[image]

This is what I have tried:

Code:

```
\begin{align*}
    6 \times \left( 3+5 \right) &=  6 \times \left( 8 \right) &&= 48\\
    6 \times \left( 3+5 \right) &= 6 \times 3 + 6 \times 5 &= 18 + 30 &= 48
\end{align*}
```

Output:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help you can  provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a solution using `matrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{matrix}
        2\times(8-3)&=&2\times5&=&10,\\
        2\times(8-3)&=&2\times-2\times3&=&16-6&=&10.
    \end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Solution using matrix environment]

Comment: @R.Morales thank you for accepting my answer!

Comment: The spaces around the `=` signs are too large.

Comment: @barbarabeeton bello Barbara!! Nice to hear you again. Thanks for the comment, I realized it some months ago when I talked with David or someone else. The spacing is not correct.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to use the `alignat` environment, which gives you full control on the spacing between alignment columns. See it this code befits you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    6 \times \left( 3+5 \right) &= 6 \times \left( 8 \right) &&= 48\\
    6 \times \left( 3+5 \right) &= 6 \times 3 + 6 \times 5 &= 18 + 30 &= 48
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The space before the `=` after `6 \times 5` is too narrow.  This can be rescued by entering it as `&{}=`.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. `align` has a right-left alignment around `&` while you want some elements to be centred;
2. `align` inserts a large space between successive `&` to separate equations.

I'd suggest `alignat` with some box manipulations thanks to [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  2 \times (8 - 3) &=       \eqmakebox[c1]{$2 \times 5$}        &       & \eqmakebox[c2]{}         = 10, \\
  2 \times (8 - 3) &= \eqmakebox[c1]{$2 \times 8 - 2 \times 3$} & {}={} & \eqmakebox[c2]{$16 - 6$} = 10.
\end{alignat*}


\begin{alignat*}{2}
  6 \times ( 3 + 5 ) &=     \eqmakebox[c3]{$6 \times ( 8 )$}      &       & \eqmakebox[c4]{}           = 48, \\
  6 \times ( 3 + 5 ) &= \eqmakebox[c3]{$6 \times 3 + 6 \times 5$} & {}={} & \eqmakebox[c4]{$18 + 30$} = 48.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

`\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` aligns all `<stuff>` (set in text mode) with the same `<tag>` according to the specified `<align>`ment (default is `c`entre, otherwise it can be `l`eft or `r`ight).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{tabular}{llll}
   6 $\times$ ( 3+5 )  &  = 6 $\times$ ( 8 ) & &= 48\
     6 $\times$ ( 3+5 ) & = 6 $\times$ 3 + 6 $\times$ 5 &= 18 + 30 &= 48
\end{tabular}
How about trying this? \left( and \right) are in math mo

Comment: With this solution the sapces around the `=` will be uneven.

Comment: What does "\left( and \right) are in math mo"  refer to?

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
 6 $\times$ ( 3+5 ) & = & 6 $\times$ ( 8 ) & = &&=& 48\\
  6 $\times$ ( 3+5 ) & = &6 $\times$ 3 + 6 $\times$ 5 &= &18 + 30 &=& 48\\
   \end{tabular}
```

I added extra tabular columns for each = sign to improve according to your suggestions. When we write maths equations we use `\(` and `\)`. In normal text one need not have back slashes for these brackets. For brackets [], and { } one had to use back slashes, because these brackets are a part of commands. You can test this sentence, "Here I am writing (good news) that we are safe.  But quarantine is creating [tension] and {health problems}." Please feel free to comment on it.

Comment: Is this an extension to your previous answer? If so, why don't you edit said previous answer instad of adding a new one?

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tabular}{clcc}
  $   6 \times \left( 3+5 \right)$ & $= 6 \times \left( 8 \right)$ &&= 48\\
  $ 6 \times \left( 3+5 \right)$ & $= 6 \times 3 + 6 \times 5 $&$= 18 + 30$ &= 48
 \end{tabular}
```

You can try this. This looks better than align.